# Actual query is slower than what explain shows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have about 200K documents of user posts. I have created the following indexes in order - _id, user's organization, post status, userid

user's organization is String; 
post status is integer (possible values 0,1,2); 
userid is String.

I use the following query and it took **4 seconds** to complete...

```
db.tickets.find({o:"alphacorp", st:1, u:"myid"}).sort({_id:-1}).skip(0).limit(10)
```

So, then I use the same query with explain and as you can see the results **nscanned** is 11 objects, **scanandorder** is false and it took **3ms**.

```
db.tickets.find({o:"alphacorp", st:1, u:"myid"}).sort({_id:-1}).skip(0).limit(10).explain("executionStats")
```

Explain output is

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_ reverse",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 10,
"nscannedObjects" : 11,
"nscanned" : 11,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 41,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 71,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 3,
"indexBounds" : {
    "_id" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [...],
"server" : "Hoover:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
}
```

Why is my query without explain taking so much time when mongodb is scanning only 11 objects and stats seem faster?

I have tried running the query, then the explain and then the query again in various patterns. So it is not an issue of initially loading to memory.

All operations are on the "localhost" so there is no network connection involved.

Comment: Did you reset any caches before running the second query?

Comment: @Brody no. I did not. I tried the query with & without explain in different sequence/order and it shows the same output.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - No. When I run the same query successive times, it does not reduce the query time. I understand what you are pointing to but its strange the output takes the same amount of time +/- couple of milliseconds...

Comment: @BlakesSeven - Yes. I tried this sequence. without-explain (4 sec) > with-explain (3ms) > without-explain (4 sec) > without-explain (4 sec) > without-explain (4 sec) > without-explain (4 sec) > with-explain (3ms)